# How to send an snmp trap as a non-root user?

Tags: net-snmp

I'm trying to send a trap using snmptrap. It works fine if I run as root.

If I run as a non-root user, I get lots of errors about "Cannot find module (XYZ): At line 0 in (none)". eg, HOST-RESOURCES-MIG, HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES, UCD-DISKIO-MIB, ...

I assume there's some files it can't read. Is there a simple way to run snmptrap as non-root? Or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Those errors don't look related to requiring root privileges. Likely you have different environment (specifically net-snmp default paths to MIBs) for the different users ?

Try

```
net-snmp-config --default-mibdirs
```

for each users. In my own setup I see output something like this:

```
/Users/some_user/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs
```

See [netsnmp page](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Using_and_loading_MIBS) for more detail on use of -M and -m flags to set up environment per user.